# Python: Check if list item has a complement

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list:

```
 listA = ['P', 'Q', ['not', 'R'], ['not', 'S']]

 Input1 : ['not','P']    - Return True as complement exists
 Input2 : 'S'            - Return True as complement exists
```

I want to determine if ['not','P']  (compliment of P) exists in above list (listA). It exists in this case so should return True.

How can I do this in python? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def comp(el):
    if type(el) == str:
        return ['not', el]
    else:
        return el[1]


listA = ['P', 'Q', ['not', 'R'], ['not', 'S']]
comp(['not', 'P']) in listA  # True
comp('S') in listA  # True
```

a better approach, though, might be to wrap your logic values in a class:

```
class Logic_Value(object):
    def __init__(self, name, negation=False):
        self.name = name
        self.negation = negation

    def __neg__(self):
        return Logic_Value(self.name, not self.negation)

    def __str__(self):
        return '~' + self.name if self.negation else self.name
```

Then checking if the negation is in the list becomes:

```
P = Logic_Value('P')
-P in listA  # True if not P is in listA
```